# Checkpoint and Lazy writer are consuming more CPU without any jobs/transactions are running on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a development server on which there are no jobs/transactions running but the lazy writer and checkpoint are consuming more CPU. What could be the reason behind this? Please refer to below screenshot and advise anybody.

[image]

Comment: These waits could be harmless and indicate a healthy state. SQL Server is always doing something, even when there is no load. I would be more interested in what is returned by sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks. Also, you may get better answers if you post this over at --> https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: >>>SQL Server is always doing something, even when there is no load<<< Checkpoint and LazyWriter do NOT "doing something" when there is no load. And in fact, there WAS writing activity as checkpoint wrote nearly 1Gb of data.

Comment: pleae consider accepting answers that help you.

Comment: sepupic My comment was meant to imply that the query above is not a good indicator of the current load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lazy writer and checkpoint are consuming more CPU.

No. Not "consuming", "consumed", at some point in the past. These sessions are currently just waiting around for any work to do, not consuming any resources.

Next time you modify some tables in the database they will wake up and write the changed data into the database files.  When they do they will consume some CPU and perform some IO before going back to sleep, and you'll see that those values increased a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @david-browne-microsoft. I was under impression that the above cpu column displays the current utilization. Thanks a lot for bursting the myth. Could you please explain in detail about this resource consumed and resource consuming. I would be grateful to you.

Comment: For each session, SQL Server tracks the total cumulative resource utilization.  So if you look at a session that has been connected for 18 days, you'll see the total CPU and IO that that session has consumed over those 18 days.

Comment: Thanks @david-browne-microsoft. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

People have blogged about which wait types are harmless and can be safely ignored from performance monitoring. For example, some wait types indicate that a thread pool is polling for work, which is not an indication of something bad. Here is article I came across a while back, it is 2012'ish, however, it still has pertinent information -->

http://thomaslarock.com/2012/05/are-you-using-the-right-sql-server-performance-metrics/

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use `compatibility view`s like `sys.sysprocesses` unless you are on `SQL Server 2000`. The column you meant is not even well documented and it's not clear if these are cpu ticks or smth else.

You should use this code:

```
select session_id, cpu_time
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id in (4, 15);
```

for the `spid`s mentioned above, and you'll see that your `system processes` do well.